# How to change JPlane position?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I tried create some window application. I have container which consist a JFrame and two  JPanel (white square and red square. The last square inside white square).

I want change position red square ( any place on my work window( for example, left  or right side)). I tried do it, but i didn't have success.

Could you help me?

It's my code)

```
import java.awt.*;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;  

public class main_window extends JFrame {  


        public static void main(String\[\] args) {  



        JFrame frame = new JFrame();  


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();

        panel_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.red);

        panel.add(panel_1);

        frame.setSize(800,800); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }  

}
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably going to need to use a different layout manager with more options, something like `GridBagLayout` for example

Comment: I tried, but it's very difficult ( i couldn't normal set GridBagLayout) . Maybe, exist different way to solve my issue?

Comment: The answer to your question will depend greatly on what it is you're trying to achieve, "why" do you need to change the position of the panel

Comment: Why not simply paint over everything and then move the *figures in the panel*? (by drawing them again)

Comment: I'm trying develop  some application for my work (It's monitoring  network program).  My need create 2- 3 line that help me understand network situation...  I want create several empty  place in my program for new monitoring line which i will add in future.

Comment: @Zero149 - If one of the answers resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking it as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently.

Answer (score 1):

`GridBagLayout` will give you the greatest amount of control over the layout itself.

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(50, 50);
                }
            };
            pane.setBackground(Color.RED);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            // Left
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            // Right
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            // Top
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            // Bottom
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            // Top/left
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            // Top/Right
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
            // Bottom/left
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHHWEST;
            // Bottom/Right
            //gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
            // Middle
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            add(pane, gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

    }
}
```

It's also the most complex layout manager, so it might take some time and experimentation to get it just right.

Start by having a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FlowLayout` to control the position of the red square.I have set layout to the outer panel with white background to control the position of the inside panel `panel_1` which is the red square.Check my answer.

```
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();  

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();

        panel_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.red); 

        panel.add(panel_1);

        //FlowLayout.RIGHT, LEFT, CENTER
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT)); 

        frame.setSize(800,800); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform some action in order to move the square e.g. I have added a button in my code which when clicked, will cause the square to move. For the button to perform some action, you need to implement `ActionListener`. As you can see in the `actionPerformed` method, I am generating random x and y coordinates of the top left corner of the rectangle and setting new coordinates by using the method, `setBounds`. Note that I have maintained the same width and height of the rectangle when it is moved to new coordinates.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel panel, panel_1;
    JButton btnMoveSquare;
    Random random;
    MainWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel_1 = new JPanel();

        panel_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.red);

        panel.add(panel_1);

        btnMoveSquare = new JButton("Move Square");
        btnMoveSquare.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(btnMoveSquare);

        setSize(800, 800);
        random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int x = random.nextInt(800);
        int y = random.nextInt(800);
        panel_1.setBounds(x, y, panel_1.getWidth(), panel_1.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment if you have any doubt with the code.

Comment: (Please explain your code sample and what the code does)